# SendInput doesn't work in a game unless I add delays. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, sendinput

I am trying to use [The SendInput API](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput) to automatically press a key repeatedly in a game WITHOUT having to use delays. I want the key presses to be as quick as possible, so I'd like to stay away from using delays like the *Task.Delay* or *Thread.Sleep* methods.

Focus on the *Strum* method.

The code below will press the right SHIFT key 18 times whenever the user uses the Ctrl + B hot key.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guitar_Hero_Strumming
{
    public partial class GHSForm : Form
    {
        public GHSForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static async void Strum()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++)
            {
                var nInputs = new[]
                {
                    new INPUT
                    {
                        type = InputType.KEYBOARD,
                        U =
                        {
                            ki =
                            {
                                wScan = ScanCodeShort.RSHIFT
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                SendInput((uint)nInputs.Length, nInputs, INPUT.Size);
                await Task.Delay(1);
                nInputs = new[]
                {
                    new INPUT
                    {
                        type = InputType.KEYBOARD,
                        U =
                        {
                            ki =
                            {
                                wScan = ScanCodeShort.RSHIFT,
                                dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                SendInput((uint)nInputs.Length, nInputs, INPUT.Size);
                await Task.Delay(1);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        private const int ModControl = 0x0002;
        private const int WmHotkey = 0x0312;

        private void GHSForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHotKey(Handle, 1, ModControl, (int)Keys.B);
        }

        private void GHSForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(Handle, 1);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WmHotkey && (int)m.WParam == 1)
            {
                Strum();
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
            int cbSize);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct INPUT
        {
            internal InputType type;
            internal InputUnion U;

            internal static int Size
            {
                get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
            }
        }

        internal enum InputType : uint
        {
            MOUSE = 0,
            KEYBOARD = 1,
            HARDWARE = 2
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        internal struct InputUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            internal MOUSEINPUT mi;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            internal KEYBDINPUT ki;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct MOUSEINPUT
        {
            internal int dx;
            internal int dy;
            internal int mouseData;
            internal MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags;
            internal uint time;
            internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct KEYBDINPUT
        {
            internal VirtualKeyShort wVk;
            internal ScanCodeShort wScan;
            internal KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
            internal int time;
            internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct HARDWAREINPUT
        {
            internal int uMsg;
            internal short wParamL;
            internal short wParamH;
        }

        [Flags]
        internal enum MOUSEEVENTF : uint
        {
            ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,
            HWHEEL = 0x01000,
            MOVE = 0x0001,
            MOVE_NOCOALESCE = 0x2000,
            LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
            LEFTUP = 0x0004,
            RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
            RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
            MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
            MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
            VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
            WHEEL = 0x0800,
            XDOWN = 0x0080,
            XUP = 0x0100
        }

        [Flags]
        internal enum KEYEVENTF : uint
        {
            EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
            KEYUP = 0x0002,
            SCANCODE = 0x0008,
            UNICODE = 0x0004
        }

        internal enum VirtualKeyShort : short
        {
            LBUTTON = 0x01,
            RBUTTON = 0x02,
            CANCEL = 0x03,
            MBUTTON = 0x04,
            XBUTTON1 = 0x05,
            XBUTTON2 = 0x06,
            BACK = 0x08,
            TAB = 0x09,
            CLEAR = 0x0C,
            RETURN = 0x0D,
            SHIFT = 0x10,
            CONTROL = 0x11,
            MENU = 0x12,
            PAUSE = 0x13,
            CAPITAL = 0x14,
            KANA = 0x15,
            HANGUL = 0x15,
            JUNJA = 0x17,
            FINAL = 0x18,
            HANJA = 0x19,
            KANJI = 0x19,
            ESCAPE = 0x1B,
            CONVERT = 0x1C,
            NONCONVERT = 0x1D,
            ACCEPT = 0x1E,
            MODECHANGE = 0x1F,
            SPACE = 0x20,
            PRIOR = 0x21,
            NEXT = 0x22,
            END = 0x23,
            HOME = 0x24,
            LEFT = 0x25,
            UP = 0x26,
            RIGHT = 0x27,
            DOWN = 0x28,
            SELECT = 0x29,
            PRINT = 0x2A,
            EXECUTE = 0x2B,
            SNAPSHOT = 0x2C,
            INSERT = 0x2D,
            DELETE = 0x2E,
            HELP = 0x2F,
            KEY_0 = 0x30,
            KEY_1 = 0x31,
            KEY_2 = 0x32,
            KEY_3 = 0x33,
            KEY_4 = 0x34,
            KEY_5 = 0x35,
            KEY_6 = 0x36,
            KEY_7 = 0x37,
            KEY_8 = 0x38,
            KEY_9 = 0x39,
            KEY_A = 0x41,
            KEY_B = 0x42,
            KEY_C = 0x43,
            KEY_D = 0x44,
            KEY_E = 0x45,
            KEY_F = 0x46,
            KEY_G = 0x47,
            KEY_H = 0x48,
            KEY_I = 0x49,
            KEY_J = 0x4A,
            KEY_K = 0x4B,
            KEY_L = 0x4C,
            KEY_M = 0x4D,
            KEY_N = 0x4E,
            KEY_O = 0x4F,
            KEY_P = 0x50,
            KEY_Q = 0x51,
            KEY_R = 0x52,
            KEY_S = 0x53,
            KEY_T = 0x54,
            KEY_U = 0x55,
            KEY_V = 0x56,
            KEY_W = 0x57,
            KEY_X = 0x58,
            KEY_Y = 0x59,
            KEY_Z = 0x5A,
            LWIN = 0x5B,
            RWIN = 0x5C,
            APPS = 0x5D,
            SLEEP = 0x5F,
            NUMPAD0 = 0x60,
            NUMPAD1 = 0x61,
            NUMPAD2 = 0x62,
            NUMPAD3 = 0x63,
            NUMPAD4 = 0x64,
            NUMPAD5 = 0x65,
            NUMPAD6 = 0x66,
            NUMPAD7 = 0x67,
            NUMPAD8 = 0x68,
            NUMPAD9 = 0x69,
            MULTIPLY = 0x6A,
            ADD = 0x6B,
            SEPARATOR = 0x6C,
            SUBTRACT = 0x6D,
            DECIMAL = 0x6E,
            DIVIDE = 0x6F,
            F1 = 0x70,
            F2 = 0x71,
            F3 = 0x72,
            F4 = 0x73,
            F5 = 0x74,
            F6 = 0x75,
            F7 = 0x76,
            F8 = 0x77,
            F9 = 0x78,
            F10 = 0x79,
            F11 = 0x7A,
            F12 = 0x7B,
            F13 = 0x7C,
            F14 = 0x7D,
            F15 = 0x7E,
            F16 = 0x7F,
            F17 = 0x80,
            F18 = 0x81,
            F19 = 0x82,
            F20 = 0x83,
            F21 = 0x84,
            F22 = 0x85,
            F23 = 0x86,
            F24 = 0x87,
            NUMLOCK = 0x90,
            SCROLL = 0x91,
            LSHIFT = 0xA0,
            RSHIFT = 0xA1,
            LCONTROL = 0xA2,
            RCONTROL = 0xA3,
            LMENU = 0xA4,
            RMENU = 0xA5,
            BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6,
            BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7,
            BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8,
            BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9,
            BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA,
            BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB,
            BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC,
            VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,
            VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
            VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
            MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
            MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1,
            MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2,
            MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
            LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4,
            LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5,
            LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6,
            LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7,
            OEM_1 = 0xBA,
            OEM_PLUS = 0xBB,
            OEM_COMMA = 0xBC,
            OEM_MINUS = 0xBD,
            OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE,
            OEM_2 = 0xBF,
            OEM_3 = 0xC0,
            OEM_4 = 0xDB,
            OEM_5 = 0xDC,
            OEM_6 = 0xDD,
            OEM_7 = 0xDE,
            OEM_8 = 0xDF,
            OEM_102 = 0xE2,
            PROCESSKEY = 0xE5,
            PACKET = 0xE7,
            ATTN = 0xF6,
            CRSEL = 0xF7,
            EXSEL = 0xF8,
            EREOF = 0xF9,
            PLAY = 0xFA,
            ZOOM = 0xFB,
            NONAME = 0xFC,
            PA1 = 0xFD,
            OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE
        }

        internal enum ScanCodeShort : short
        {
            LBUTTON = 0,
            RBUTTON = 0,
            CANCEL = 70,
            MBUTTON = 0,
            XBUTTON1 = 0,
            XBUTTON2 = 0,
            BACK = 14,
            TAB = 15,
            CLEAR = 76,
            RETURN = 28,
            SHIFT = 42,
            CONTROL = 29,
            MENU = 56,
            PAUSE = 0,
            CAPITAL = 58,
            KANA = 0,
            HANGUL = 0,
            JUNJA = 0,
            FINAL = 0,
            HANJA = 0,
            KANJI = 0,
            ESCAPE = 1,
            CONVERT = 0,
            NONCONVERT = 0,
            ACCEPT = 0,
            MODECHANGE = 0,
            SPACE = 57,
            PRIOR = 73,
            NEXT = 81,
            END = 79,
            HOME = 71,
            LEFT = 75,
            UP = 72,
            RIGHT = 77,
            DOWN = 80,
            SELECT = 0,
            PRINT = 0,
            EXECUTE = 0,
            SNAPSHOT = 84,
            INSERT = 82,
            DELETE = 83,
            HELP = 99,
            KEY_0 = 11,
            KEY_1 = 2,
            KEY_2 = 3,
            KEY_3 = 4,
            KEY_4 = 5,
            KEY_5 = 6,
            KEY_6 = 7,
            KEY_7 = 8,
            KEY_8 = 9,
            KEY_9 = 10,
            KEY_A = 30,
            KEY_B = 48,
            KEY_C = 46,
            KEY_D = 32,
            KEY_E = 18,
            KEY_F = 33,
            KEY_G = 34,
            KEY_H = 35,
            KEY_I = 23,
            KEY_J = 36,
            KEY_K = 37,
            KEY_L = 38,
            KEY_M = 50,
            KEY_N = 49,
            KEY_O = 24,
            KEY_P = 25,
            KEY_Q = 16,
            KEY_R = 19,
            KEY_S = 31,
            KEY_T = 20,
            KEY_U = 22,
            KEY_V = 47,
            KEY_W = 17,
            KEY_X = 45,
            KEY_Y = 21,
            KEY_Z = 44,
            LWIN = 91,
            RWIN = 92,
            APPS = 93,
            SLEEP = 95,
            NUMPAD0 = 82,
            NUMPAD1 = 79,
            NUMPAD2 = 80,
            NUMPAD3 = 81,
            NUMPAD4 = 75,
            NUMPAD5 = 76,
            NUMPAD6 = 77,
            NUMPAD7 = 71,
            NUMPAD8 = 72,
            NUMPAD9 = 73,
            MULTIPLY = 55,
            ADD = 78,
            SEPARATOR = 0,
            SUBTRACT = 74,
            DECIMAL = 83,
            DIVIDE = 53,
            F1 = 59,
            F2 = 60,
            F3 = 61,
            F4 = 62,
            F5 = 63,
            F6 = 64,
            F7 = 65,
            F8 = 66,
            F9 = 67,
            F10 = 68,
            F11 = 87,
            F12 = 88,
            F13 = 100,
            F14 = 101,
            F15 = 102,
            F16 = 103,
            F17 = 104,
            F18 = 105,
            F19 = 106,
            F20 = 107,
            F21 = 108,
            F22 = 109,
            F23 = 110,
            F24 = 118,
            NUMLOCK = 69,
            SCROLL = 70,
            LSHIFT = 42,
            RSHIFT = 54,
            LCONTROL = 29,
            RCONTROL = 29,
            LMENU = 56,
            RMENU = 56,
            BROWSER_BACK = 106,
            BROWSER_FORWARD = 105,
            BROWSER_REFRESH = 103,
            BROWSER_STOP = 104,
            BROWSER_SEARCH = 101,
            BROWSER_FAVORITES = 102,
            BROWSER_HOME = 50,
            VOLUME_MUTE = 32,
            VOLUME_DOWN = 46,
            VOLUME_UP = 48,
            MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 25,
            MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 16,
            MEDIA_STOP = 36,
            MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 34,
            LAUNCH_MAIL = 108,
            LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 109,
            LAUNCH_APP1 = 107,
            LAUNCH_APP2 = 33,
            OEM_1 = 39,
            OEM_PLUS = 13,
            OEM_COMMA = 51,
            OEM_MINUS = 12,
            OEM_PERIOD = 52,
            OEM_2 = 53,
            OEM_3 = 41,
            OEM_4 = 26,
            OEM_5 = 43,
            OEM_6 = 27,
            OEM_7 = 40,
            OEM_8 = 0,
            OEM_102 = 86,
            PROCESSKEY = 0,
            PACKET = 0,
            ATTN = 0,
            CRSEL = 0,
            EXSEL = 0,
            EREOF = 93,
            PLAY = 0,
            ZOOM = 98,
            NONAME = 0,
            PA1 = 0,
            OEM_CLEAR = 0,
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the *Strum* method contains 2 instances of the *Task.Delay* method. The code above will NOT work if I remove the 2 instances of the *Task.Delay* method.

**Why does the keyboard input not send if I remove the delays?**

**How can I send the keyboard input without having to use the delays?**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does this change the result? (note, deliberately removed the async return type)

```
private static void Strum()
{
    var inputs = new[]
    {
        new INPUT
        {
            type = InputType.KEYBOARD,
            U =
            {
                ki =
                {
                    wScan = ScanCodeShort.RSHIFT
                }
            }
        },
        new INPUT
        {
            type = InputType.KEYBOARD,
            U =
            {
                ki =
                {
                    wScan = ScanCodeShort.RSHIFT,
                    dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP
                }
            }
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++)
    {
        SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, INPUT.Size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea, but sadly no.

Comment: Shucks, that's all I have to offer other than cramming all 36 into one SendInput call. Oh, and in my solution above I just realized I should have removed the async return value (edited now). I am beginning to think that's the source of the problem.

Comment: You think that async is the source of the problem? SendInput doesn't work at all unless a delay is used. Thread.Sleep and Task.Delay both work to make SendInput work. :I